# Couldn't enter the data to mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

It couldn't store the data to mysql. What to do? All variable and file name are correct.

```
     <?php
require 'connection.php';
$conn    = Connect();
$id    =$conn->real_escape_string ($_POST['id']);
$name    = $conn->real_escape_string ($_POST['name']);
$phone    = $conn->real_escape_string ($_POST['phone']);
$address    = $conn->real_escape_string ($_POST['address']);
$city    = $conn->real_escape_string ($_POST['city']);
$zip   = $conn->real_escape_string ($_POST['zip']);
$state    = $conn->real_escape_string ($_POST['state']);
$item    = $conn->real_escape_string ($_POST['item']);

$status    = $conn->real_escape_string ($_POST['status']);
$enquiry_date    = $conn->real_escape_string ($_POST['enquiry_date']);
$enquiry_user = $conn->real_escape_string ($_POST['enquiry_user']);
$query   = "INSERT into enquiry
           (id, name, phone, address, city, zip, state, item, status, enquiry_date, enquiry_user) 
           VALUES('" . $id . "','" . $name . "','" . $phone . "','" . $address . "','" . $city . "','" . $zip . "','" . $state . "','" . $item . "','" . $status . "','" . $enquiry_date . "')";
$success = $conn->query($query);



if (!$success) {
    die("Couldn't enter data: ".$conn->error);
}

echo "Thank You For Contacting Us <br>";

$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: Using prepared statements would solve the job of escaping string and quotes

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: `$enquiry_user` is missing as last param

Comment: error:couldn't enter data

Comment: @FelippeDuarte surely meant the response of `$conn->error()`

Comment: (I suppose 'enter code here' is not in your original code)

Comment: It'll also be helpful to see the html form

Comment: @Jeff, Is the rest code are correct?

Comment: You're already using an API that supports **prepared statements** with bounded variable input, you should utilize parameterized queries with placeholders (prepared statements) to protect your database against [SQL-injection](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/)!
 Get started with [`mysqli::prepare()`](http://php.net/mysqli.prepare) and [`mysqli_stmt::bind_param()`](http://php.net/mysqli-stmt.bind-param).

Comment: @Akintunde I1sec I am giving you the code

Comment: Like already asked, does `$conn->error` give anything? Have you enabled PHP error reporting?

Comment: @MunnaKumar we will see once you've fixed the two I pointed out.

Comment: You seemingly forgot to add a value to `enquiry_user`. You have one more column than you do values. `$conn->error` would have told you about that.

Comment: @Jeff $conn  function declared in another php page called connection.php

Comment: Yes, we know where $conn is coming from. `echo $conn->error` gives you the information about the error you have (which @Qirel and I told you already)

Comment: trahimaan trahimaan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Jeff said:

```
$query   = "INSERT into enquiry
       (id, name, phone, address, city, 
        zip, state, item, status, enquiry_date, enquiry_user) 
       VALUES('" . $id . "','" . $name . "','" . $phone . "','" . $address . "','" 
        . $city . "','" . $zip . "','" . $state . "','" . $item . "','" 
         $status . "','" . $enquiry_date . "','" . $enquiry_user . "')";
```

You were missing **`. "','" . $enquiry_user`**

Comment: That semi-sort of fixes it. The real problem here is not using placeholder values.

Comment: @tadman I agree. But that requires a lesson and examples, and I follow Larry Wall's philosophy

Comment: Larry Wall didn't advocate leaving your code vulnerable to SQL injection exploits because of preventable mistakes. [DBM supports placeholder values](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBI/lib/DBD/DBM.pm).

Comment: @tadman hahaha. No, but he did advocate that **I** be lazy and not do someone else work .. I **100% agree** with you that he needs to learn it.

Comment: @JacquesAmar [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52343928/how-to-fetch-data-using-foreach-in-one-form-codeignter?sfb=2] can you help me in this code