# How to fetch data using foreach in one form codeigniter

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter

I want to know the most relevant method to do this in Codeigniter. I was actually using this to populate `<options> </options>` in form

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="int">Clients Id <?php echo form_error('clients_id') ?></label>
<select class="form-control select2 select2-hidden-accessible" se="width: 100%;">   
<center><option selected="selected">--- Select ---</option></center>
<?php
foreach ($invoices as $invoices) {
?>  
<option class="form-control select2" value=" <?php echo $invoices->clients_id; ?>"><?php echo $invoices->first_name; ?> 
</option>
<?php
}
?></select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="int">Suppliers Id <?php echo form_error('suppliers_id') ?></label>
<select class="form-control select2 select2-hidden-accessible" se="width: 100%;">   
<center><option selected="selected">--- Select ---</option></center>
<?php
foreach ($invoices as $invoices) {
echo "<pre>"; print_r($invoices);die;
?>  
<option class="form-control select2"  value=" <?php echo $invoices->service_id; ?>"><?php echo $invoices->service_name; ?> 
</option>
<?php
}
?></select>

</div>
```

This function is in my model. Is there any best method to execute.

```
    function join() {
        $this->db->select('*');    
$this->db->from('invoices');
$this->db->join('clients', 'invoices.id = clients.id');
$this->db->join('services', 'invoices.id = services.id');

      $query = $this->db->get();
      return $query->result();

        }
```

Is it the right method. To call the Invoice data. Actually, entire code works properly but when I call `foreach()` It, Shows error. Thank you in Advance.

```
public function create() 
    {
        $data = array(
            'button' => 'Create',
            'action' => site_url('invoices/create_action'),
        'id' => set_value('id'),
        'clients_id' => set_value('clients_id'),
        'services_id' => set_value('services_id'),
        'suppliers_id' => set_value('suppliers_id'),
        'contractors_id' => set_value('contractors_id'),
        'charges_id' => set_value('charges_id'),
        'particulars' => set_value('particulars'),
        'details' => set_value('details'),
        'price' => set_value('price'),
        'date' => set_value('date'),
        'due' => set_value('due'),
        'paid' => set_value('paid'),
    );
        $this->load->view('invoices_form', $data);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all check your query using `echo $this->db->last_query();` put this code in `controller` where you write `$data['invoices']` and then check its working or not then use below code in your `view` part.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="int">Clients Id <?php echo form_error('clients_id') ?></label>
    <select class="form-control select2 select2-hidden-accessible" style="width: 100%;">   
        <center><option selected="selected">--- Select ---</option></center>
        <?php
            foreach ($invoices as $row) 
            {

                echo '<option class="form-control select2" value="'.$row['client_id'].'">'.$row['first_name'].'</option>';
            }
        ?>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="int">Suppliers Id <?php echo form_error('suppliers_id') ?></label>
    <select class="form-control select2 select2-hidden-accessible" se="width: 100%;">   
        <center><option selected="selected">--- Select ---</option></center>
        <?php
            foreach ($invoices as $row) 
            {

                echo '<option class="form-control select2"  value="'.$row['service_id'].'">'.$row['service_name'].'</option>'
            }
        ?>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: It Displayed        SELECT * FROM `invoices` JOIN `clients` ON `invoices`.`id` = `clients`.`id` JOIN `services` ON `invoices`.`id` = `services`.`id`
@rudra

Comment: run this query on phpmyadmin and make sure it run perfectly @MunnaKumar

Comment: If this query run then use above code that I have mention @MunnaKumar

Comment: I have recently edited the above code.. It may be more helpful to understand.

Comment: Please tell me your query run or not @MunnaKumar

Comment: check my edit code @MunnaKumar

Comment: If answer is useful then make sure click on vote @MunnaKumar

Comment: I have mentioned the query above and we are close enough.